# Email functionality in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I need to know from where default magento fires emails for new orders .Kindly help me here.
I need to add in emails different "from email-ids" for different microsites

Answer (score 0):

Give

> from email-ids

in magento admin **system->configuration->store email addresses**.
for microsites, select **Select configuration scope** in top left of magento admin panel and choose website and give the from email ids.